# When allies have leaders of the same ideological orientation in power at the same time - does it improve their foreign relations?

Tags: ideology, foreign-policy, trade

When allied countries, let's say amongst the Five Eyes for brevity, have compatible political parties in power at the same time - does it improve concrete foreign policy and trade objectives?

For instance, a recent alignment on the Right of:

- `David Cameron <-> Stephen Harper <-> Tony Abbot <-> John Keys`

A recent alignment on the Left of:

- `Barack Obama <-> Gordon Brown <-> Kevin Rudd`

Comment: @DVK An explanation of whether and why ideological alignment has improved concrete outcomes or policy initiatives, with an example of such an outcome cited by a political analyst. I've narrowed the scope to traditional allies with a shared culture, as naturally geopolitical shifts between fair weather friends or regional frenemies would overshadow and obscure this trend if it exists.

Comment: correllation != causation. It'd be VERY difficult to prove that the ideological alignment was the cause of specific outcome, outside analyst's personal opinion. The sample size is small enough that a reliable pattern or baseline is hard to establish :(

Comment: @DVK Yes, there is a chance that this is never openly acknowledged; but given the size of the Washington grapevine and stream of memoirs, I hoping someone let something slip. I know for instance that several Aussie politicians (when they had some spare time in opposition) went to multi-day conservative conferences in the US and left-wing politicians have done the same at international labour conferences. One has to wonder if this is a surface indication of preferential alignment when respective politicians eventually gain leadership.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. It depends on the ideology too. Two leaders favoring protectionism are likely to engage in a trade war if the circumstances arise. As recent history has shown, one leader might actually be enough for that, as the others would feel forced to respond to some extent.